# How to create the group chat in android

Tags: android, sockets, chat

Hi I am implementing Chat application using sockets this one working fine.Now I want to Add group chat for the same app.How my chat application working means first user need to signup with some details and then it will generate the username and password based on user need to login with the details.After login  user don't have any friends and then send friend request will send to another friend then that friend will accept the request now both are friend.Now they can communicate with each other.

After that it will show friend's list up to this i did.After that I want to create the group chat this one I don't know how to create the group chat for the app.

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)

Its works using device IMEI number.[LINK](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)